# Подсчёт времени с момента последнего запроса к БД с текущей страницы

Tags: php, mysql

Необходимо реализовать подсчёт времени с момента последнего запроса к БД с текущей страницы. То есть необходимо сделать так, что если пользователь не обращался к БД 30 минут с текущей страницы, то его автоматически выкидывало с личного кабинета.

Comment: а если у него две страницы открыты? в одной работает а в другой нет?

Comment: Сессии в помощь, дергать базу для таких вещей не является целесообразным решением

Comment: @teran Хорошее замечание

Comment: MoloF Тогда уже придется отслеживать не частоту запросов БД наверное, а браузерные события(перемещение мыши и т.д.)?

Comment: @Данила в том же редисе есть TTL (время жизни), ставите 30 минут и данные автоматически удалятся, вам остается сделать только проверку и все.